# Mетод Audio.Add — Access denied: no access to call this (VK API)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, token

Добрый день, друзья. 
При попытке использовать метод `Audio.Add` API VK, возвращается следующая ошибка:

> "error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this
>   method

При получении токена я указываю `scope=audio,offline`.

Уже начинаю грешить, а не закрыл ли vk.com эту возможность?

Comment: Покажите ваш код по которому обращаетесь к API

Answer (score 0):

https://vk.com/dev/audio_api

С 16 декабря 2016 года VK отключило публичный API для работы с аудиозаписями. Существующие методы секции audio будут недоступны для вызова, кроме методов для загрузки аудиофайлов.